# list-style not shown on horizontal list

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal list in my markup with the following CSS:

```
ul li {
   display: inline;
   list-style: circle;
   list-style-type: circle;
}
```

When I remove the `display: inline;` it works fine. But I can't get it to work on the horizontal one.

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Comment: @imtheman you could create your own very easily. Nothing fancy here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, if you do that it won't shw because you're basically declaring "stop displaying the element in its default display method `list-item` and use `inline` instead" . To learn more about display methods, please take a look do [DISPLAY PROPERTY](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop).

Now, if you want to have bullets AND still display it inline, there are many ways to do it. You can use a :before pseudo-selector, you can use a background, etc.

For example:

```
ul li {
  display: inline;
}

ul li:before {
  content: "• ";
}
```

or

```
ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li{
  padding-left:30px; background:url(images/bullet.png) no-repeat 0 50% ;
}
```

but as long as you "kill" the `list-item` display method, you'll need to find some ways to override the DOM display of list types

Comment: if using the first solution, i recommend `content: "\25E6 "` instead, for two reasons: it's the character code and won't break even in a poorly-made text editor, and it's an "open bullet" rather than "closed bullet" (it looks more like the `list-style: circle`). [example](http://jsfiddle.net/52kvnyu8/)

Answer (score 3):

The list decorators will only be displayed if you don't override the display type for the list item. Rather than setting `display: inline`, apply a `float: left` and give some margin to prevent the circles from colliding into the previous element.

```
ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  list-style: circle;
  list-style-type: circle;
}
```

[Here is an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ltemxo9/)

```css
ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  list-style: circle;
  list-style-type: circle;
}

/* this bit is optional, it only removes the left padding from the first item */
ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> item 1 </li>
  <li> item 2 </li>
  <li> item 3 </li>
  <li> item 4 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inline, use:

```
li {
   float:left
}
```

or

```
li {
   display:inline-block
}
```